# Hide the NSViewController in MAC OSX

Tags: macos, swift

I am trying to hide the controller view because if the user has already logged in,it gets the default username and password and without showing the login window controller(hiding it) does the operation of signin in the background and after successfully logging in closes the hidden window and opens the mainViewController.

```
  let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let email = defaults.stringForKey("email")
    {
        emailTextField.stringValue = email as NSString
    }
    if let password = defaults.stringForKey("password")
    {
        passwordTextField.stringValue = password as NSString
    }
    self.signIn(self)
```

This is in the viewdidload() and gets the default values of username and password.

```
  var mainStoryBoard:NSStoryboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())!
  var containerWindow:ContainerWindow = mainStoryBoard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("ContainerWindow") as ContainerWindow
  containerWindow.showWindow(AppManager.sharedInstance.main)
  AppManager.sharedInstance.login?.close()
```

This is the in the signIn function when all the operations are completed it shows the mainView controller and closes the login window controller.Now i want to hide the login window controller at the start.Is there a way to do that?